# ASP.NET item to display "stoplight" data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net

I'm looking for a tool, object, or library to use with ASP.NET (or possibly Javascript, but preferred ASP.NET) to achieve the below grid. Each cell corresponds to a 0, 1, or 2 value (0 being red, 1 being yellow, 2 being green) stored in a DataTable. The number of cells varies between sections, so if they can be dynamically created it would be preferred. Two sections ("aisles") are shown, but there will be dozens of aisles.

If it is available in basic ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2012 that would be best. I also have access to DevExpress tools.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty (yet) but I ended up using standard ASP.NET buttons created dynamically inside of panels, in lieu of a suitable control.

I create a Panel control in the code behind, and fill it with Button objects, one per row for the aisle, with zero padding. I added a label to act as a header with the aisle name. I repeat this process for each aisle.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Essential Grid for ASP.NET](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/grid/defaultfunctionalities.aspx) can be used to implement this, but each Grid has to be created separately as shown in this [sample application](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/138469/sqlbinding-746917470.zip). The sample application has two grids bound to SQL Datatable and use the QueryCellInfo event in common for both grids to change the background color of the cell based on the value.

Essential Studio is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program.

[image: Screenshot]
- Davis (Syncfusion)